# Are operators not being used properly in this python function definition?

Tags: python

I am trying to define a function which takes a string argument and yields `1` if the string is a, c, e or g and yields `0` if the string is b, d, f or h.

```
def ifodd_str(col):
    if col == 'a' or 'c' or 'e' or 'g':
        return 1
    elif col == 'b' or 'd' or 'f' or 'h':
        return 0

ifodd_str('a')
```

The problem is `ifodd_str('b')` returns `1`. What is wrong with my if statements?

Comment: `if col in ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']:`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you're not actually comparing `col` to the intended characters. You're checking the value of each character, which will always return true.

You have to compare equality for each individual case:

```py
if col == 'a' or col == 'c' or col == 'e' or col == 'g':
    # do something
```

You can also use a list to test this:

```py
if col in ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']:
    # do something
```